# Parametrization of $3 \times 3$ real orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, parametrization, orthogonal-matrices

I want to be able to write: *"Suppose $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ orthogonal matrix. Then $A$ is of one of the following forms: ..."* I need some parametrization of a general $3 \times 3$ orthogonal matrix.

Wikipedia [gives the following parametrization on its page on orthogonal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix#Higher_dimensions):

$$\small\begin{bmatrix}
\cos (\alpha)\cos (\gamma)-\sin (\alpha)\sin (\beta)\sin (\gamma) & -\sin (\alpha)\cos (\beta) & -\cos (\alpha)\sin (\gamma)-\sin (\alpha)\sin (\beta)\cos (\gamma) \\ 
\cos (\alpha)\sin (\beta)\sin (\gamma)+\sin (\alpha)\cos (\gamma) & \cos (\alpha)\cos (\beta)  & \cos (\alpha)\sin (\beta )\cos (\gamma )-\sin (\alpha )\sin (\gamma) \\ 
\cos (\beta)\sin (\gamma) & -\sin (\beta)  & \cos (\beta)\cos (\gamma)
\end{bmatrix}$$

The article is very confusingly written right now. This matrix is given without much information. It's parametrized by three angles $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, and I've checked its determinant to be $1$ using Mathematica, so I *assume* that this parametrizes the orthogonal $3 \times 3$ matrices with determinant $1$, i.e., all rotations about the origin. However, it also says:

> *but [...] the non-rotational matrices can be more complicated than reflections.*

mentioning something about rotoinversions, and

> *However, we have elementary building blocks for permutations, reflections, and rotations that apply in general.*

without further explanation of what on earth that means.

Am I correct in assuming that **all orthogonal matrices are either parametrized by the above matrix or its additive inverse**? In other words, would adding a $\pm$ sign in front of the above parametrization for $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ give me one for $\mathrm{O}(3)$?

Comment: If their matrix is correct, then negating does negate the determinant and you get everything. Computer people seem to like using the unit quaternions for rotations of $\mathbb R^3,$ very popular. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Advantages_of_quaternions

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3145242/339790)